# Ctrl+L in terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I accidentally typed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in terminal and my terminal window jumped one 'screenful' size. I looked at the keyboard shortcuts in "Edit"->"Keyboard shortcuts" and didn't find that shortcut.

What does <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> do and where is it defined?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> just clear the terminal screen.

It is the keyboard shortcut equivalent of the command `clear -x`. <sup>[ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434240/ctrll-in-terminal/434243#comment1882071_434243)</sup>

It is property of `bash`, so you did not found it under **keyboard shortcuts** in your gnome-terminal. From `man bash`:

```
clear-screen (C-l)
          Clear the screen leaving the current line  at  the  top  of  the
          screen.   With  an  argument,  refresh  the current line without
          clearing the screen.
```

See a detail list of [Bash Keyboard Shortcuts](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html).

Comment: Oh, that explains it.

Comment: It's not just bash though;  Ctrl-L is the form-feed character.  It's not so common, but sometimes you'll see ^L in source code separating "pages" of code.  It made more sense when a printer would interpret it as a control character.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you are correct. Related wiki article on [Page break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break)

Comment: ^L is the form-feed character in the ascii table, but that doesn't do anything unless it is received by a program that treats it accordingly (either bash or the terminal emulator, in this context).

Comment: Note that it is not the equivalent of the default command `clear`, because it doesn't erase your terminal history, while the command `clear` does, unless you add the `-x` argument, like so: `clear -x`.

Comment: @jirislav thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the post. By the way, can you tell me where did you get the `-x` option of `clear`? `man clear` did not help me.

Comment: @souravc I see it in the manual, maybe you have different version of the `ncurses-bin` package? I have 6.1.

Comment: @jirislav thank you. You are correct. It seems that few options are added in the `clear` man pages from 18.04 onwards i.e. from ncurses version 6.1

Comment: Ctrl-L is often intercepted by CLI programs and interpreted as "redraw the screen". for example, `vim`, `less`, and most n-curses applications will redraw the display when they receive a Ctrl-L character. It's more or less a de-facto standard.

Answer (score 21):

If the shell you're using is not intercepting it, you are typing a "Form-feed" character in your terminal. If the terminal application does not intercept or use the keystroke in some way, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Letter is translated to the ASCII code of the letter minus 64(1). 65 is the ASCII code of 'A', 'L' is the 12th letter -> code 76. If the shell does not know what to do of the code, it prints it.

Printing a FF char resulted in a new page on a line printer and a clear screen on the terminal (yes, I used a [VT-52](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT52) back then, at 300 baud).

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is 12 which is FF. In the same way, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is a TAB, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> rings the bell --- if the terminal or the shell does not intercept it, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for example.

Notice from the other answer: it seems that bash **do** intercept <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> and do a `clear`. Nice touch that the `bash` authors associated the key with a command which will do more or less the same that the ASCII code did on old terminals!

On the other hand, in my `zsh` the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> works as <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> as a <kbd>Backspace</kbd>(2).

Old nice ASCII... (notice that letter L is at column 4, row 12, it has ASCII code 4*16+12=76).

[image: Image from Wikimedia commons]

Original Image [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII_Code_Chart-Quick_ref_card.jpg), from [wikipedia article on ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

---

Footnotes:

(1) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> really used to clear the bit 7.

(2) this is the source of the "fail to remove word" joke you sometime find like for example "this was a bad^H^H^Hnot so nice idea"... (with normally a word stronger than bad!)

Comment: Nice. How do I use this chart by the way? I can see that letter L is at row 12 and column 4. Do I then just minus 32 from the 124 or how do you calculate the ASCII code?

Comment: @AvatarParto ups, wrote 32 instead of 65. Answer corrected. The table is binary, so the code is column*16+row.

Comment: Inserting literal `^H`s or `^W`s is nice when you can't use strikethroughs. :)

Answer (score 7):

`Control-L` is intercepted and interpreted by bash (actually by [the `readline` library](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Interaction.html), which handles interactive editing on the command line). It is bound to the `clear-screen` function, as @souravc wrote.

**Note on the meaning of `Control-L`:** It is defined as Form Feed in the ASCII character table, but this means nothing unless some program interprets it accordingly. The terminal does not clear the screen when it sees a form feed, as you can verify by by saving a ^L in a file and printing the file with `cat`. When `bash/readline` sees the `^L`, it executes the `clear-screen` function. This sends a sequence of characters that is understood by your terminal emulator (as described by termcap or terminfo), and has the effect of clearing the screen.

In very old printers, a `^L` would advance the paper start printing on the next sheet, hence the name "form feed". But modern terminals and terminal emulators follow a newer ANSI standard, in which control commands are multi-character ["escape codes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Sequence_elements) that begin with `^[` (escape). When bash sees your `^L`, it is probably sending the two-command sequence `ESC [ H ESC [ J`, which moves to the top left of the screen and clears everything below it (hence the whole screen).

Comment: Actually, the sequence `ESC [ ESC [ J` also clears the command history, whilst the `CTRL + L`  sequence doesn't. 

The sequence sent to the terminal is rather `ESC [ H ESC [ 2 J`, go ahead an try it yourself with this command: `printf "\033[H\033[2J"`.