# Shortcut to clear command line terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Is there a shortcut to clear the command line when typing in it instead of keeping backspace pressed for a few long seconds?

I ask because I regularly use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to automatically fill in file names when using bash commands in the Terminal. For example instead of typing `cd this_is_a_long_file_name`, I will type `cd th<Tab>`. But then I realize I have filled in the wrong command/filename and I have to hold down backspace to clear everything and repeat the process.

Comment: See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/434240/ctrll-in-terminal

Comment: "Ctrl+c cd" is the short cut you are looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9679852/6521116

Answer (score 164, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will only clean from the cursor to the beginning of the line, so if the cursor is at the end of the line, all the line will be cleaned, and if not, there will remain the characters after the cursor.

For a complete answer, I will say:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> - clear all the current line from the end to the beginning only if the cursor is at the end of the line.

  - You can then recall the cleared line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> if you need.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> - clear all the current line from the beginning to the end only if the cursor is at the beginning of the line.

  - You can then recall the cleared line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> if you need.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - clear the previous word in the current line. For example if you have typed a command like `git diff /path/to/some/file` and you want to delete just the last parameter to the command, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is very useful.

  - You can then recall the cleared data using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> if you need.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> - move the cursor to the end of the line and clear all the current line from the end to the beginning.

  - You can then recall the cleared line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> if you need.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> - move the cursor at the beginning of the line and clear all the current line from the beginning to the end.

  - You can then recall the cleared line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> if you need.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - *my favourite* - cancel the current command line, which implies clear all the current line no matter where the cursor is.

  - Disadvantage: you can't recall the cleared line anymore.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> - comment the current line, keep it in the history and bring up your prompt on a new line.

Comment: There's also Ctrl+L, which outputs a bunch of newlines to hide previous output. (I know the question is about the input line itself)

Comment: @Kroltan It is the same as writing "clear". But ctrl+L is shorter. Happy to learn it.

Answer (score 24):

A shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> should do what you want.

Comment: and `Ctrl+l` for clearing the screen (a bit like a `stty -sane`, but maybe a bit less potent and far reaching). `Ctrl+l` works in many apps, as well (it forces a redraw in vi, for example. Usefull when someone "write" or "wall" on it)

Answer (score 17):

If you realized you pressed the wrong key, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (underscore, you may need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> depending on your keyboard layout, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> a US keyboard) to undo the last editing command.

If you realized that you typed the wrong command name but the argument is right, you can use cursor movement commands such as arrow keys, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> to navigate to the part of the command line that you want to modify.

The commands <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> move back and forth by one word at a time. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> delete the next word after the cursor, or the end of the word if the cursor is within a word; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> uses the shell's notion of a word while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> uses whitespace-separated words. <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the word before the cursor.

If you want to abandon the current command line completely and start afresh, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Ctrl-c` to cancel the current command, this also works if you haven't yet pressed enter. It will not clear the terminal though, only bring up your prompt on a new line. To clear the visual part of the terminal, you may press `Ctrl-l`