# Bash completion for commands that start with specified letter?

Tags: command-line, bash

Is it possible when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and after this, for example, press the letter `a`, then using the up and down arrow key to search only the commands in the history that start with `a`? Or if I type `ssh` and then use the arrow keys to search commands that start with `ssh`.

Is there a script that can implement this?

Comment: What you are asking is not called [`bash completion`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can even avoid the need of typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> by adding these two lines to your [`~/.inputrc`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9):

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Up and down arrows will continue to browse your history if you press them at the bash prompt. But it will search for a command starting with the text to the left of the cursor if you type the beginning of a command like `ssh`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But with pressing ctrl+r it doesn't work, which is not a problem because only pressing a letter and then arrow key is faster. Just making a note.      

    Is there a shortcut that can clear the active command? In Windows command prompt pressing ESC clear the typed commands and return the cursor in the beginning but in linux pressing ESC doesn't do that.

Comment: @user1800997 See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/470971/32239)